# If you are using Closed Hashing (Open Addressing), is it not possible to store all the data?

Tags: hash

Okay so i know the size of the Hash table should be the largest prime number closest to the size of the data set. So if you employ Closed Hashing (Open Addressing), each key location will correspond to 1 data. Thus its impossible to store all the data in the hash table? Then whats the point of hashing you data, when you will lose some of your data in the hash table?

Thanks in advance for any clarifications.

P.S i know that this can be solved by using Open Hashing (Separate Chaining), as each key location can have more than 1 data.

Comment: Of course not, you use the next available bucket in case of collision.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case you would use the **next** prime number after the data set size so your hash table can hold all data points.

Alternatively, motivation for choosing a prime number **smaller** than max possible data set size could be when a real-world situation where you know ahead of time that only a sparse set of data points will be used in any given hash table instance